# How to make carousel like in Skipperlimited

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making something and want to design it like http://www.skipperlimited.com/

But I don't know how to go about that carousel of images and the carousel inside their logo.
Can someone show some way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can ask for help if any error occur in you code and every one who knows will help you, but you cant ask someone to write your code. The question is not following asking norms of stackoverflow. see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am really sorry for that. But, I don't know how to do that, how can I ask for error.I am not asking for code, just that if someone could drop a hint how to do that, I can do..

Comment: Thank you, I got to know how they have made it, after a hard brain strom lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is "to show some way" - and I think this question is reasonable and perfectly well answerable. Not everything has to be code, sometimes it is also about the how-to-start / how-to-get-there. Various approaches are possible, here is my way:

I would study the source code via the "Developer Tools" that every browser offers. There I can see that the images themselves are prepared in an already very stylish way that has nothing to do with HTML. Here is a direct link to one of their images:

http://repository.skipperlimited.com/images/home-images/home-bg3.jpg

Furthermore, I see that the other text is positioned over the image using an absolute positioned container called "home-wrapper". Here, the absolute positioning AND the z-index are important: the text must be layered over the image container.

In the head tag, I can also see that jquery.bxslider.js is included, so you might wanna checkout that library and work through their documentation.

In order to find out, how the buttons work: they seem to have event listeners attached to them. So, again in the devTools, I find them in the source code and check the "EventListeners" tab in the devTools. There is a list of event listeners currently active on the element, and I see that a "jquery.bxslider" event is attached to those little squares.

And so forth.

This would be my way to explore. I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks buddy, I had just did that and found this... Was about to delete the question lol...

Comment: You need to have a certain amount of points here on stackoverflow and a certain role, as far as I know, to be able to delete a question again. To be honest, I never really cared about that. Stackflow is a mysterious place, where there are ghost, who, instead of (also) helping simply exercise power... Non-stop-Halloween... Checkout the forums at css-tricks. They seem to have a positiver attitude towards helping out each other. Or find a channel on gitter or slack that fits your topic... and upvote my answer, please ;-) G'day and g'luck!

Comment: Yeah Sure, Thankyou :) :)